# Feedparser Date parameter/Time-specific query

Tags: python, rss, feedparser

Is there an Option in feedparser to query only the new entries newer then feed.updated?

Or can you set a parameter to get only entries from a specific date/today/week etc.? (Safari´s RSS Reader provides this options...)

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand the question as written.  An RSS feed is an XML document.  Feedparser retrieves and parses this entire document.  It can't query just part of a document.  It's up to you to write the code around feedparser to extract what you want (e.g., for each entry, you can look at d.entries[0].date and compare it with another date/time stamp or range to determine if you're interested in it or not).

I don't know what you mean by looking for entries newer then feed.updated, since there shouldn't be any (the newest entries would have been entered when the feed was last updated).

Comment: Thx, i did it like that. i thought there is something like querry-date option in rss like a REST-based service, but i think i thats another point and it´s not regarding RSS as a format or whatever it is.